# Stuck Partway Through This Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

"Use a Laplace Transform to solve $x''+x = sin2t$; $x(0) = 0, x'(0) = 0$"

**My Work So Far**

$x'' = s^2X(s) - sx(0) - x'(0)$

$\therefore $

$s^2X(s) - sx(0) - x'(0) +X(s) = \frac{2}{s^2+4}$

$s^2X(s) +X(s) = \frac{2}{s^2+4}$

$X(s) =\frac{2}{(s^2+4)(s^2+1)}$

From here, though, I'm not sure what the next step would be to come up with a form that can be solved for the inverse transform. Any help moving past this step would be appreciated.

Comment: Factorize and partial fraction decomposition : $\frac{2}{(s+2)(s-2)(s+i)(s-i)} = \frac{A}{s+2}+\frac{B}{s-2}+\frac{C}{s+i}+\frac{D}{s+i}$ where $A = \lim_{s \to -2} (s+2)X(s)$ and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$X(s) =\frac{2}{(s^2+4)(s^2+1)}=\frac{2}{-3}\left(\frac{1}{s^2+4}-\frac{1}{s^2+1}\right)$$
then
$$x(t) =\frac{2}{-3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin2t-\sin t\right)$$

Comment: You beat me by 8 seconds.

Comment: @Dr.MV you are great!

Comment: I'm far from great.  But thank you my friend!  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\frac{1}{(s^2+1)(s^2+4)}=\frac{1/3}{s^2+1}-\frac{1/3}{s^2+4}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to given you the best answer I can.  -Mark